# extract data from file with python

Tags: python

I need to extract data from lines of a text file. The data is name and scoring information formatted like this:

```
Feature_Locations:
   - { x:9.0745818614959717e-01, y:2.8846755623817444e-01,
       z:3.5268107056617737e-01 }
   - { x:1.1413983106613159e+00, y:2.7305576205253601e-01,
       z:4.4357028603553772e-01 }
   - { x:1.7582545280456543e+00, y:2.2776308655738831e-01,
       z:6.6982054710388184e-01 }
   - { x:9.6545284986495972e-01, y:2.8368893265724182e-01,
       z:3.6416915059089661e-01 }
   - { x:1.2183872461318970e+00, y:2.7094465494155884e-01,
       z:4.5954680442810059e-01 }
```

This file is generated by another software.
Basically I want to get that data back in this program and i want to save them in different other files for examples "axeX.txt" "axeY.txt" "axeZ.txt"

I have try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
file = open('data.txt', "r")
for r in file:
    y = re.sub("- {", "",r).split()
    tt = y[:2]
    zz = tt
    st = re.findall('\d+', r)
    print st
file.close()
```

Is there a better way or I am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
s = open('data.txt', "r").read()

x = re.findall(r'x:(.*), ', s)
y = re.findall(r'y:(.*),', s)
z = re.findall(r'z:(.*) ', s)

with open('axeX.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(x))
with open('axeY.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(y))
with open('axeZ.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(z))
```

Comment: Work fine ! Thank you so much ! :D

Answer (score 1):

The input file is in YAML format. It is recommended to use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) package for parsing yaml files.

```
import yaml

document = """
Feature_Locations:
   - { x: 9.0745818614959717e-01, y: 2.8846755623817444e-01,
       z: 3.5268107056617737e-01 }
   - { x: 1.1413983106613159e+00, y: 2.7305576205253601e-01,
       z: 4.4357028603553772e-01 }
   - { x: 1.7582545280456543e+00, y: 2.2776308655738831e-01,
       z: 6.6982054710388184e-01 }
   - { x: 9.6545284986495972e-01, y: 2.8368893265724182e-01,
       z: 3.6416915059089661e-01 }
   - { x: 1.2183872461318970e+00, y: 2.7094465494155884e-01,
       z: 4.5954680442810059e-01 }
"""

locations = yaml.load(document)['Feature_Locations']

for ch in 'XYZ':
    fname = 'axe%s.txt' %ch
    with open(fname, 'w') as fh:
        for item in locations:
            fh.write('%s\n' % item[ch.lower()])
```

The input file is slightly corrupted. [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will do a sanity check and inform us of the errors.

```
yamllint inputfile.yaml
inputfile.yaml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
  2:9       error    syntax error: found unexpected ':'
```

In this case we can fix the input file easily.

```
 sed -i 's/:/: /g' inputfile.yaml
```

Comment: It seems you had to preprocess the document by adding spaces between the variables (x, y, z) and the actual values. Is there any straightforward way of doing that using PyYAML?